# design issue, base class knows its derivative

Tags: c++, base-class

Basically I have a base class called `Geometry`, and some derivative such as `Point`, `Polygon`, etc...

`Geometry` implements a method intersection like this :

```
Geometry* intersection(Geometry* other)
{
     Geometry* inter = compute_intersection(this, other); 

     if (inter is a polygon) 
         return new Polygon(inter);

    if (inter is a point) 
         return new Point(inter);
}
```

When I compute the intersection of two geometries in my program, I obtain a `Geometry*` and I can `dynamic_cast` it to whatever it really is.

Is it a good design ? What, I think, might be wrong is that I have to check real type each time I compute an intersection and dynamic_cast the result (which can be slow). But what I think is the main problem is that with this design, `Geometry` must know its derivative (Point, Polyline? etc...).

What could be a good solution to avoid these problems ?

Comment: You need a Abstract Factory design pattern.

Comment: @Als it is not pure Factory, but he has it implemented already...

Comment: is this really how your code looks like? I have a feeling you haven't told the whole story...

Comment: Just use a virtual function that returns a `Geometry*` and invoke it on the return value of `compute_intersection`. That way, the version of that function for the various derived classes can return a pointer to a `Point` or `Polygon` as appropriate.

Comment: Do `Polygon`, `Point` and other derivates of `Geometry` implement methods not present in the `Geometry` interface?

Comment: @David so I should implement intersection for each derived class ?

Comment: @juanchopanza yes they have some specific methods

Comment: You may need to implement intersection for each combination of derived classes, I'm afraid. That's a question about the nature of the algorithms used though.

Comment: Isn't your problem the infamous multiple-dispatch ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#C.2B.2B

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to construct a new object of the returned object, can't you jsut return it straight away? If you can not, just implement one additional method in each derivative class that wraps the result from `compute_intersection` in a new object and call this new method instead of `compute_intersection` in `Geometry`.

In my answer I assume the only possible situation: `compute_intersection` is abstract and each deriving class implements it.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself needing to new according to inherited type to copy objects, then you can use [virtual copy constructors](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8), by implementing a clone() function that returns a copy of the object:

```
virtual Obj* Obj::clone() const { return new Obj(*this); }
```

This can be called from your intersection() function.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here as far as I'm concerned.

Firstly, I don't care much for functions which get/set things. I'm more interested in telling objects to do something for me.

Secondly, you are trying to implement multiple dispatch (in this case double dispatch). This is where the behaviour you want depends upon the types of multiple objects.

My normal mantra of *encapsulate, encapsulate, encapsulate* guides me towards the following ideas:

- Encapsulate what you want to do with the intersection e.g.

  - Put its area into a spreadsheet cell
  - Add geometry points to a display list
- Encapsulate the dispatch of one type given another type

  - Look into the visitor pattern
- Encapsulate applying the behaviour to an intersection

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/variant.html):

```
typedef boost::variant<Point, Polygon/*, and other...*/> Geometry_Variants;

Geometry_Variants intersection(Geometry_Variants const& other)
{
    // compute the intersection and return Point or Polygon
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is known under the name: `multiple dispatch` or `multi methods`. There is no real good answer to this problem in C++ as far as I know. A good discussion of this problem by Andrei Alexandrescu is here:

http://books.google.fr/books?id=aJ1av7UFBPwC&pg=PA263&lpg=PA295&dq=modern+c%2B%2B+design+multiple+dispatch&source=bl&ots=YRdIZrWiaV&sig=2Vj0Blst_jmhMCAZIJ8gUiG_pl4&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=082XT86RHNS18QPW7f3mBQ&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

I recommend you to buy the book it's worth its price.